# How to read different parts or blocks of a file with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file that consists of 'blocks' of data where the header says how many blocks are in the file and how many lines are in each block.

```
# mydata.dat
3 12343 2
# comment
12343
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
12343
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
12343
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I'd like to store each block separately. What I've done is to generate a list from each block by splitting lines and then converting it to an array to store in a dictionary.

```
import numpy as np

with open('mydata.dat', "r") as f:
    lines = f. readlines()
    blocks, _, n = map(int, lines[1].split())
    del lines[:3]
data = {i: np.array(dtype=float,
                    object=[line.split()
                            for line in lines[i * n + 1: n * (i + 1)]])
        for i in xrange(blocks)}
```

I feel there should be a better (more 'efficient') way to parse the data in the text blocks directly, something like `np.loadtxt` where you can skip a periodic amount of rows (like slicing) and not just from the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadtxt` does what you do for each block - read each line, split it, convert it according to `dtype` and append it to a list, and finally convert that to an array.

It has been pointed out in other questions that you can pass an opened file, or any iterable to the `loadtxt`.  So you can preprocess the file, divide it into blocks, skip lines, etc.  But overall it isn't going to be any more 'efficient' than what you are doing.

So this might work (I haven't tested it):

```
data = {i: np.loadtxt(lines[i * n + 1: n * (i + 1)], dtype=float)
    for i in xrange(blocks)}
```

It's more compact, but I doubt if it is faster.

The only other approach I can think of is to strip out all the block size lines, pass the remaining to `loadtxt` to get an array of all the data, and then split it into the blocks, e.g. with `np.split(...)`.

With `txt` as list of lines from your sample:

```
In [396]: timeit np.array([line.split() for line in txt[4:6]],dtype=float)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13 µs per loop
In [397]: timeit np.loadtxt(txt[4:6],dtype=float)
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, already tried them and they work. Still, splitting by hand and using `np.array` seems to be faster than just `np.loadtxt` or `np.split`, do you know why that is?

Comment: Less overhead?  As I tried to describe, `loadtxt` isn't doing anything special with compiled code.  `pandas` has a faster `csv` loader.

Answer (score 1):

`np.loadtxt()` can take an iterable, so you can pass it slices of `line`
The first row of data is row 2.

```
with open('mydata.dat', "r") as f:
    # load data, skipping comment lines
    line = [s for s in f if not s.startswith('#')]

    # parse first line to find out block size
    _, _, blocksize = map(int, line[0].split())

    # use np.loadtxt() to convert slices of the input
    data = [np.loadtxt(line[i:i+blocksize])
            for i in range(2, len(line), blocksize+1)]
```

You can skip loading the file into a string first by using `itertools.islice`:

```
with open('mydata.dat', "r") as f:
    # iterator over lines in f with comment lines removed
    lines = (line for line in f if not line.startswith('#'))

    # parse block structure
    nblks, _, blksz = map(int, next(lines).split())

    # convert "islice"s of the input file to np.arrays
    # start arg to islice is 1 to skip over block header line
    data = [np.loadtxt(it.islice(lines, 1, blksz + 1)) for i in range(nblks)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.loadtxt` can take any iterable as parameter, and strip white-spaces to get a data array.

The following code gives np.loadtxt an iterable that yields full blocks, not lines.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice

def chunks(iterable, blocks_count, block_size):
   for i in range(blocks_count):
       yield "".join(islice(iterable, block_size))

with open(r'c:\tmp\tmp.txt', "r") as f:
    file_iterator = iter(f)
    next(file_iterator) # skip first comment line
    blocks, _, n = map(int, next(file_iterator).split())
    next(file_iterator) # skip second comment line
    blocks_iterator = chunks(file_iterator, blocks, n)
    data = dict()
    i = 0
    for arr in np.loadtxt(dtype=float, fname=blocks_iterator):
        data[i] = arr
        i += 1
```

Comment: Pretty neat, didn't know loadtxt could read iterables. I think you forgot about the 'header' of each block because your code returns `---> 16     for arr in np.loadtxt(dtype=float, fname=blocks_iterator):` `...` `ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2`

Comment: Fixed it by modifying it to `yield "".join(islice(iterable,  block_size+1))`. But it runs slower and it is also more code.